# Animating rotation along edge

Tags: animation, edges

I'm animating a product and I want to rotate an object along an edge which is not aligned to any global axis.
[**I found out**](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28829/set-edge-as-axis-for-surface-rotation) that rotation is possible in **Edit mode**, set **Pivot Point** as **Active Element** and change **Transform Orientation** to **Normal**.

It just doesn't seem possible to Insert Keyframe for Location & Rotation in Edit mode. This way, I just change the overall specs of the object without animating the rotation of it.
**[Here is a video example of the problem](https://youtu.be/GxObv8JdOJU)** where I attempt to rotate the object 20 degrees.

*Does anyone know how to solve this / make this work?*

Comment: You should align your object with the global axis, parent it to an empty, rotate the empty the way you want in order to align with the edge, then animate the object, its new global orientation is now relative to the empty, see my answer here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/129834/how-do-i-rotate-an-object-along-its-own-axis-windmill/129836

Comment: Also related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/140629/custom-rotation-for-a-tilted-aircraft-flap  A lot will depend on usage. With  parenting directly, or with an  empty inbetween , via an armature or with axis angle:  sets up the ability  to keyframe  a single channel which  quite likely will  reduce headaches later.

Comment: Thanks @batFINGER @ moonboots for your answers! I looked at both of them.
I'm using a complex imported .svg file for the shapes of my animaton. This means that aligning all objects with the global axis to parent it to an empty, is a lot of work (unless it's possible to align an empty to the axis of the object???).
So, I tried the bone method, which seems to work well! I'm going to give every object a bone, and will continue the animation when every object is boned. Thanks again!

Comment: I stumbled upon a new problem, but first: the bone armature mothod works! 
I started animating, and found out that some objects did have Armatures, but they were not assigned as Bone (see video: https://youtu.be/NMPotn01ox8 ).
If I adjust them now, the objects will jump to another location. Set Inverse and Clear Inverse returns the objects to their original locations, so that doesn’t work either.
Is there any way to prevent the displacement? Or do I have to go back in the animation and correct the objects before starting to animate?

Comment: I figured it out already! I just have to go back to the keyframe before the parent object starts moving, and assign the armatures as bone + set inverse. The rest of the animation stays intact that way :). In my case, the order of < assigning armature as bone + Set inverse > is important because multiple objects are parented to other parented objects.