# Fold a plane. then fold again

Tags: animation, shape-keys

Imagine a piece of paper and you fold it in half and then fold it again. that's what I am trying to do and cant. If I use bones the influence of the bones won't allow me to because I need 2 bones to control the same area. If I try shape keys it just deforms the mesh if I try to make it in multiple steps or does the wrong animation because it draws the shortest path instead of rotating from a point like a piece of paper would.[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hinge bone armature.**

In the second part of [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/210085/15543) I wrote a script to make an armature, can be used here

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Matrix, Vector
from mathutils.geometry import intersect_point_line
import bmesh
context = bpy.context

def hinge(armob, ob, pb, face):
    arm = armob.data
    # add a bone from edge center to face center
    face.select_set(True)
    edges = [(l, f) for l in face.loops for f in l.edge.link_faces if not f.select]

    for l, f in edges:
        e = l.edge
        b = arm.edit_bones.new(f"Hinge_{f.index}")
        b.parent = pb
        pt, dist = intersect_point_line(
                f.calc_center_median(),
                e.verts[1].co,
                e.verts[0].co,
                ) 
        b.head = pt
        b.tail = f.calc_center_median()
        vg = (
                ob.vertex_groups.get(b.name) or
                ob.vertex_groups.new(name=b.name)
                )
        vg.add([v.index for v in f.verts], 1, 'ADD')
        hinge(armob, ob, b, f)

def make_armature(ob, face_index):
    me = ob.data
    bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me).copy()
    
    face = bm.faces.active
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
    bpy.ops.object.armature_add()
    arm = context.object

    mw = (
            ob.parent.matrix_world.copy() if ob.parent
            else ob.matrix_world.copy()
        )

    ob.matrix_parent_inverse.identity()
    #ob.matrix_world.identity()
    ob.parent = arm
    ob.matrix_parent_inverse = ob.matrix_world.inverted()
    ob.vertex_groups.clear()
    
    arm.matrix_world = ob.matrix_world
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
    b = arm.data.edit_bones[0]
    b.tail += face.calc_center_median()
    b.head += face.calc_center_median()
    hinge(arm, ob, b, face) 

    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')  
    for pb in arm.pose.bones[1:]:

        pb.rotation_mode = 'AXIS_ANGLE'
        pb.rotation_axis_angle = (0, 1, 0, 0)
    ob.modifiers.clear() 
    mod = ob.modifiers.new(
            "Hinger",
            type='ARMATURE',
            )
    mod.object = arm 
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='POSE') 
make_armature(context.object, 0)
```

With the mesh in edit mode, select one face, Run the script, creates an armature, with root bone at that face.

[image]

Now with the armature in pose mode <kbd>Shift</kbd> select the two bones going same way to fold. Can <kbd>Alt</kbd> change the property of one to change same property  all selected. Type in 180 to fold in half.

[image]

Now the slightly tricky bit because the script wasn't designed to do this... <kbd>Shift</kbd> select the two bones going the other way. Change the axis of one by negating the X axis (1 -> -1) this will ensure both spin the same way for this fold. (*Alternately one to 180 and one to -180 degrees, will do same.*)

Now same as before press  <kbd>Alt</kbd> and change the angle, and rotate to 180.

[image]

Comment: Holly shit this is amazing. It works so well I am about to cry. thanks, man. I had to do another fold and it worked by changing to -1 also this great!!