# Folding box panels - panels deforming and not connected

Tags: animation, armature, weight-painting, vertex-groups

I am trying to fold a box to create an animation. The 90 degree folds are all working well, but the box has an angled flap that would double fold to create a bevelled corner. These do not seem to fold well at all.

Although they are kept offset, they fold the side panel out of sync with the armatures, deform the corners and seem to deform and shrink the panel itself. So far I have:
-Created a set of armatures to individual vertex goups.

- Kept the side panel armatures on 'keep offset'
- tried weight paitning (but didn't seem to respond when i tried painting out the overly red areas.)

Any help would be appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Are the X or Z axis of the bones perfectly aligned with the lines of the desired folds? Weight paint affects only vertices, not areas: area moves when its vertices move.

Comment: Does this answer help? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/210073/how-to-parent-bones-to-the-panels-of-a-dieline-package-paper-folding.

Comment: pls provide blend file since we have no idea how you did setup this