Rotating a flap of an airplane
I want to animate this airplane and control the wings using drivers. How can I properly rotate the wing so that it doesn't collide with the object?
I also tried using an armature but couldn't get it to work.
How can I define the rotation axis myself?




Hello, maybe read this answer https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/129834/how-do-i-rotate-an-object-along-its-own-axis-windmill

@moonboots how about this answer of yours? :) https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/140629/custom-rotation-for-a-tilted-aircraft-flap

oh you're right i forgot this one
